# Where does Kubernetes store logs from Jobs by default?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, fluent-bit, kubernetes-jobs

I know that pod logs are stored at `/var/log/containers/<pod-name>.log`. Are jobs stored in the same location? The job spins up a pod and I can view the logs with `kubectl logs <pod-name>`, but I have fluent-bit configured and was expecting to see the logs for that container in fluent bit, but I do not. I am wondering if there is something weird in the backend for EKS that I am unaware of on how jobs may be treated differently than normal pods.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special about a Job, except that the containers in its Pod are normally expected to exit.  The Job itself doesn't have logs, only its corresponding Pod(s).

Comment: First, an instance of the fluent bit daemonset has to be running on the node where you're running your job. Second, there may be something wrong with the way you've configure fluent bit. Are you filtering logs?